# Match columns with multiple entries in a row and mutate result

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
col_1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
col_2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
col_3 <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A")

df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3)
```

I want to mutate a new column that contains TRUE or FALSE depending on whether any row has more than two identical entries.

e.g.:

```
t_f <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

Even better, if I could have a column that contains the repeated values, e.g.:

```
name <- c("A", "B", "C", NA, NA, NA)
```

Comment: Title doesn't match with the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you first requirement

```
df$t_f <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x)))
```

And your second

```
df$name <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(duplicated(x)), x[which(duplicated(x))], NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R you can try

```
ifelse(colSums(table(row(df), as.matrix(df)) >= 2) == 1, colnames(table(row(df), as.matrix(df))), NA)
A   B   C   D   E   F 
"A" "B" "C"  NA  NA  NA
```

In tidyverse you can do

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dup=anyDuplicated(c(col_1, col_2, col_3))!=0) %>% 
  mutate(which.dup=c(col_1, col_2, col_3)[which(duplicated(c(col_1, col_2, col_3)))[1]])
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: <by row>
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  col_1 col_2 col_3 dup   which.dup
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr>    
1 A     A     A     TRUE  A        
2 A     B     B     TRUE  B        
3 B     C     C     TRUE  C        
4 B     D     C     FALSE NA       
5 C     E     B     FALSE NA       
6 C     F     A     FALSE NA
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second requirement:

```r
col_1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
col_2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
col_3 <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A")

df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3)

df$name <- apply(df, 1, 
      function(row)ifelse(max(table(row))>=2, 
                          names(table(row))[which.max(table(row))], NA))

df
#>   col_1 col_2 col_3 name
#> 1     A     A     A    A
#> 2     A     B     B    B
#> 3     B     C     C    C
#> 4     B     D     C <NA>
#> 5     C     E     B <NA>
#> 6     C     F     A <NA>
```